# regex replacement that adds text

Tags: regex, expression

I'm trying to do link rewriting in my mobile application (written in ruby). I would like it to be able to accomplish both of these rewrites with a single regular expression:

```
m.example.com -> www.example.com
m.subd.example.com -> subd.example.com
```

The closest I've gotten replacing this:

```
m\.([a-z\.]*)example\.com
```

with this:

```
$1example.com
```

This works for the m.subd.example.com but it fails for m.example.com because of my "www." exception.

I do this A LOT so i'd like it to be very fast, which is why I am trying to avoid using any code, just a single regex. Is it possible? Is there a fancy feature of regex that I don't know about?

Comment: Regex doesn't have *translation* (i.e. m -> www). So I think you'll need two. However, I'm curious to see some answers.

Comment: it is certainly possible to do it. But if you want to combine the two, I have to know what language you use? (you can pass matches on to functions in certain languages)

Comment: I would like to do this in both ruby and javascript, so discussions on either would be welcome.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Which, however, means using code. So it's not a single regex any more (as Andrew would have liked).

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Sure a small function would be provided to the regex engine, but that doesn't make it slow - it seems to me that speed is the real requirement. @Andrew I'm afraid Javascript can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to avoid using any code, just a single regex

Regex is code.  A more complex regex takes longer to run.  You'll need to write some code or run two regexes.

```
result = subject.gsub(/m\.([a-z.]*)example\.com/, '\1example.com').gsub(/^example\.com/, 'www.example.com')
```

Comment: Chose this answer as correct, thanks Jeremy. Unfortunately it seems that the real answer to my question is "it is not possible."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby, but here is a Perl script that does the job for the examples you've given. May be it could be translated.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @list = qw/m.example.com m.subd.example.com/;
my $re = qr#^m\.(.*)(example\.com)$#;
foreach(@list) {
  print $_;
  s/$re/($1 || "www.") . $2/e;
  print " -> $_ \n";
}
```

**output:**

```
m.example.com -> www.example.com 
m.subd.example.com -> subd.example.com
```